# Software Scanners vs. Handheld Scanners

Tags: tools

Are there any software based scanners which are comparable to a high quality hand held scanner?

Comment: [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=OBDII+bluetooth+android&safe=active)

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of scanner. OEM from the manufacturer, and after-market versions. Vehicle scanners on todays vehicles from the manufacturer allow access to the vehicles ECUs to the extent that after market scanners do not, these are only available under license. This is to prevent the theft or changing of major parts of the vehicle, or the vehicle itself. After market scanners will carry out a lot of service operations but not everything. After market scanners will report on OBD2 and will list any thing else that they are programmed to do. There is no set standard of range on after market scanners. The only differance between software and hand helds are that software versions require a laptop and a compatable DLC plug, with usually Windows or Linux op systems. You need to know what you intend to do, or are capable of doing, before buying a scanner that covers your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And because I can't leave a 3-letter answer, here's an example:

[OP-COM](http://www.op-com.hu/default_en.aspx)

> OP-COM is a Windows based diagnostic program package for Opel / Vauxhall cars.
>   The diagnostic program package covers a wide range of cars from
>   1990-2013, latest models are also included!
>   Main functions are read and clear fault codes, display live data,
>   perform output tests. Immobiliser support, remote and key fob
>   programming,
>   change variant coding of various control units, and a lot more.